# Doc2Vec: tuTypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, doc2vec

I created a doc2vec model to determine most similar documents : 
Here the  code for training :

```
#train doc2vec model
docs = g.doc2vec.TaggedLineDocument(train_corpus)

model = g.Doc2Vec(docs, dm=0, dbow_words=1, size=200, window=8, min_count=19, iter=2)
```

For ineference I try this :

```
#load model
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)
pprint(m.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"], topn=20))
```

But i Got this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-ca36e85d7a79> in <module>
----> 1 pprint(m.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"], topn=20))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in most_similar(self, positive, negative, topn, clip_start, clip_end, indexer)
   1687             if isinstance(doc, ndarray):
   1688                 mean.append(weight * doc)
-> 1689             elif doc in self.doctags or doc < self.count:
   1690                 mean.append(weight * self.vectors_docs_norm[self._int_index(doc, self.doctags, self.max_rawint)])
   1691                 all_docs.add(self._int_index(doc, self.doctags, self.max_rawint))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3):

[image]I had the same error and i found a quick fix for it.
The reason you have this error is because your function : `most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"]` takes a list of tokens in the parameter positive so you need to give a list of words and not a sentence.
Here is a fix for you :

```
def process_query(query):
    words = []
    words = query.split()
    return words

query = "machine learning"
l = process_query(query)
sim = model.most_similar(positive=l,topn=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known bug pending a fix](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1737) that if you supply a `tag` to `doc2vec_model.docvecs.most_similar()` that's not known to the model, it will show this confusing error.

So, `"Machine learning"` is not a `tag` that was supplied during training. In fact, the `TaggedLineDocument` class simply gives each document a single tag based on its line-number in the corpus file. If you want more sophisticated/descriptive tags, you'll have to prep the corpus yourself, to present individual objects (shaped like `TaggedDocument`) with both a list-of-words `words` property and a list-of-tags `tags` property.

Comment: So what should you do in case you want to see a result? I also see the same error on the first document I built my model on

Comment: If you're getting exactly this error, then the tag you're requesting is likely not in your model. Are you sure your supplied `TaggedDocument` instance had a `tags` value that was a list-of-tags, not just a single string? (If this doesn't clear things up, you may need to post a question of your own, with space for you to show the code you used to prep-your-texts, train-your-model, and prompt-the-error.)